# Error with Windows Service with running under Local system with Interop.SHDocVw.dll ieframe.dll throwing res://ieframe.dll/dnserror.htm#

Tags: c#, .net, windows-services

I am doing some screen scrapping from a website for that i have used Microsoft.mshtml and Microsoft Internet Controls

In Windows form application run fine but after bundling my application in windows service I am getting following error res://ieframe.dll/dnserror.htm# at

wb.Navigate(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("LoginUrl"), ref o, ref o, ref o, ref o);

Same Windows Service Run fine if it runs under User Account

But it throws above error when runs under Local system account

Comment: If all you're doing is screen scraping you might prefer Awesomium - http://awesomium.com/. However as to your error, have you tried running as NetworkService?

Comment: I have tried with
1. Local System   [got error res://ieframe.dll/dnserror.htm#http://mypageaddress.]

2. Local service  [got error Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {0002DF01-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} failed due to the following error: 80070005.]

3. Network Service [got error  Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {0002DF01-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} failed due to the following error: 80070005.]

4. User account  [Run successfully.]

Comment: I have a sample code at the post http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/csharplanguage/thread/d78bdffc-f85e-42c9-88b8-703371b366be